# Two shops and sync clients between them with passwords

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Is this possible to sync customers between two seperate prestashop 1.7 shops? I dont want to use multistore option..is there a module for that or maybe some database operations?

Answer (score 0):

Customers are stored in a single database table (**ps_customer**) , so if you are able to write a synchronization routine between the two database tables you should be able to achieve that.

There are several additional considerations though :

- Both stores must have the same "*cookie_key*" set in the site parameters for same passwords to be validated in both shops, so you'll have to start with at least one empty store.
- Customers have different relationships to databases based on their id_customer **auto_increment** values (addresses, orders, third party modules etc.), so you'll need to know what you're doing and make sure the two shops can't have conflicts between customer ids (IE: you can start one of the two shops with a very high id_customer..) - Also not sure if you need to handle also addresses synchronzation.. This would add some complexity.

I hope I've given you some good starting points - but I would stick with native "multishop" PS feature for that - It would be far easier despite still having a lot of bugs :)